# Communication between processes in Windows

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-process

What project (C#) type would you suggest for this situation?

Having one application for communicating with distance server from one side (I have API for communication with that server) and communication with lots of different applications (call them clients) on user computers.

I need to have only one server connection in any giving moment, but every client can have his requests separately.

Can clients communicate with server using some kind of Objects (.net objects)?

My idea is to make windows service, but I not sure is this a good approach?

Comment: WCF with SOAP is the toy you want

Comment: Can I have some kind of shared memory?

Comment: @Vasoli: Windows service can't communicate with anything itself. On the other hand, any communication technology can be implemented in several types of applications. Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Dennis I need a way to have only one instance of object which communicate to server but I need that multiply client apps share memory (data from server) without having their copy of that memory.

Comment: Use Queue for memory sharing (MSMQ, RabbitMQ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WCF InProc for inter process communication.
Check the [tutorial](http://rasor.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/howto-inproc-wcf/).

Also [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) can be used as an alternative for InProc communication.